# Can we able to take a backup of the file using wildcard

Tags: unix, wildcard, cp

we have some files like
dev_app_s01.properties
dev2_app2_s01.properties
qa_app_s02.properties

Planning to backup one of any file using wildcard suing shell script like cp *.properties *.properties_BAK_DATE

The output should be like below:
dev_app_s01.properties  to dev_app_s01.properties_BAK_DDMMYY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method could be sticking a for loop around one of these many solutions:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96380/how-to-append-date-to-backup-file

The gist would be:

```
for i in dev*_app*.properties
do
   cp {i} {i}-`date`.properties
done
```